# Chirp Driver for Yaesu FTM-300DR

Tags: yaesu, chirp

Is there a compatible available Chirp driver for the **Yaesu FTM-300DR**?  I would think of the many other Yaesu drivers available for Chirp, that something is compatable?

if there is none, the what are other ways to connect the Yaesu to the computer?  Ubuntu btw, but will use windows if i need to.

Comment: https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/FAQ#Is-my-radio-supported

Comment: In other words, had someone tried, they'd have reported that to the chirp developers and it would be on the website. The people here are quite the kind of people that would report such findings upstream!

Comment: People have already requested that someone implement that: https://chirp.danplanet.com/issues/8129 but it's one of [646 such requests](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/issues?query_id=15), so unless you can budget the time to do the necessary engineering yourself, I'll go with "nope".

Comment: the way mobile VHF/UHF rigs are programmed, two models are almost never compatible unless they're actually the *same* radio in disguise. Just being from the same manufacturer/product line isn't enough.

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G ... Which keeps surprising me, considering that if I were a manufacturer, I'd reuse are much of my software platform as possible. These are real development costs, potential for bugs, and generally dev time that you'd better invest in building capabilities that make you stand out in competition...

Comment: i'm surprised as well that the data protocols are all so proprietary, not just by manufacturer, but also by radio.  That's why I asked if someone know of a compatible, or near enough Yaesu radio that works; too bizarre to consider that each radio is unique.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Originally it was about saving costs (by transferring raw memory images instead of implementing a "smart" protocol you could save money on the MCU, ROM, etc. in the radio, because all of the real work happens on the programming machine), but today it's just a tradition that's outlived its usefulness, because $0.10 chips have all the power you need.